# Slippry slider svg arrows not showing

Tags: svg, slider

For some reason the svg arrows in my slippery slider do not show online. Works fine on my desktop, then when I upload to ftp, it does not. The svg file was provided, and I have even re-saved and replaced it, to no avail. Any ideas?

http://threeriversahec.org

html script:

```
<!-- SLIPPRY SLIDESHOW SCRIPT -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="slippry/dist/slippry.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="slippry/dist/slippry.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

slippry/dist/ > css script:

slippry/dist/assets/ > svg file

```
  .sy-controls li a:after {
  content: "";
  background-image: url(assets/arrows.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: 0;
  line-height: 2.8em;
  color: #111;
  font-weight: 800;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 2.8em;
  height: 2.8em;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1.4em;
  margin-left: -1.4em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your arrows.svg file is being served with the wrong Content-Type/MIME type.  If you look at the "Net" tab of you browser dev tools, you will see that it is being served as "text/html".  It should be "image/svg+xml".  You need to configure your web server so that it serves SVG files with the correct type.  How you do that depends on which web server you are using.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it had to be server-side.

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround is to save the arrows.svg file as a PNG file with transparency (I used Illustrator), and replace all occurrences of 'arrows.svg' with 'arrows.png' in the Slippry CSS file.